# Is it possible to import a pandas data from a CSV while reading in cell values as objects instead of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to save a list of dicts to each cell of a pandas data frame. While I can interact with these and save them to a CSV while I'm running my script, I'm not sure if there's a way load the CSV afterwards and read the strings within each cell as lists of dictionaries. For example:

```
obj1 = {'number': 22, 'popularity': 12, 'attr3': "cows"}
obj2 = {'number': 99, 'popularity': 4, 'attr3': "dogs"}
obj3 = {'number': 21, 'popularity': 0, 'attr3': "cats"}

tmp_list_1= [obj1,obj2,obj3]
tmp_list_2= [obj2,obj2,obj2]
tmp_list_3= [obj3,obj3,obj3]

list_of_lists = [tmp_list_1,tmp_list_2,tmp_list_3]
```

With this lists of lists, I can create a pandas data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list_of_lists,list_of_lists,list_of_lists])
```

All the cells within this data frame contain lists, and these lists + the dicts contained therein retain their properties (i.e., the lists act like lists — I can iterate through them).

I then save this data frame to a CSV.

```
df.to_csv("testing_list_dicts_import.csv")
```

Understandably, the values of the cells turn to strings when they're read back in via

```
tmp_import = pd.read_csv("testing_list_dicts_import.csv")
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not there's a way to import those cells not as strings, but as lists of objects.

Help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Adding CSV below:

```
,0,1,2
0,"[{'popularity': 12, 'number': 22, 'attr3': 'cows'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}]","[{'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}]","[{'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}]"
1,"[{'popularity': 12, 'number': 22, 'attr3': 'cows'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}]","[{'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}]","[{'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}]"
2,"[{'popularity': 12, 'number': 22, 'attr3': 'cows'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}]","[{'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}, {'popularity': 4, 'number': 99, 'attr3': 'dogs'}]","[{'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}, {'popularity': 0, 'number': 21, 'attr3': 'cats'}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, **no**.

This is because `python` can't tell by itself whether text in a file is actually code or just a string. To be on the safe side, it reads everything from files as strings.

However, if your data in the `.csv` is exactly as it would appear in code i.e if your data in the `.csv` looks like [x, y, z etc.] (with the square brackets and proper formatting), you could `eval()` the strings when you read them from the file to parse them as code.

Comment: Gotcha. How would I use `eval()` when reading the file in via `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: @scrollex Please can you edit your question to show the _exact_ contents of the `.csv`? (as I could help you from there)

Comment: Yup, @Adi219, have added it above!

Comment: @scrollex Sorry, I had to go! Do you need to use a `panda` dataframe when storing your data?

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty specific problem. I can iterate through the lists of objects and save each as a row with the attributes as individual columns, but am basically wondering if it's possible to just save each list as a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Designing a workflow requiring use of `eval`, or even `ast.literal_eval`, to read the contents of a csv file is not good practice. Your proposed solution will also be inefficient.

For your particular problem, you should store your dictionary and mappings separately. Store your dataframe containing integer pointers and a separate dictionary. When you need a extract a particular dictionary given a pointer *n*, just use `d[n]`.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {1: {'number': 22, 'popularity': 12, 'attr3': "cows"},
     2: {'number': 99, 'popularity': 4, 'attr3': "dogs"},
     3: {'number': 21, 'popularity': 0, 'attr3': "cats"}}

tmp_list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
tmp_list_2 = [2, 2, 2]
tmp_list_3 = [3, 3, 3]

LoL = [tmp_list_1, tmp_list_2, tmp_list_3]

df = pd.DataFrame(LoL, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

#    col1  col2  col3
# 0     1     2     3
# 1     2     2     2
# 2     3     3     3
```